# Is there a way to count based on another set of data given?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that looks something like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is give a formula values 1 through 20 from column B and count how many "No" values there are in these particular rows in column D and return the count of "No"s. This is important because I need to be able to sort by column C and still return the same value.

Is there a way to do this via formulas?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try COUNTIFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">=1",B:B,"<=20",D:D,"No")
```

If the numbers are stored as text, you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B*1>=1)*(B:B*1<=20)*(D:D="No"))
```

Comment: Thank you! One last question - if the numbers are stored as text, is there a way to convert the text to numbers using COUNTIFS?